# Renderizar uma diretiva

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Tenho um diretiva que quando carrego a página ela é renderizada, o conteúdo dessa diretiva vai sofrer algumas alterações durante o uso.

Queria um meio que ao pressionar um botão recarregasse essa diretiva para seu conteúdo padrão.

Comment: Não entendo nada de angular mas talvez o design pattern Memento ajude.

Comment: pode colocar o código para analizarmos?

Comment: Quando você cria diretivas, você pode criar variáveis por referência no `scope` dela, e utilizaria no html algo assim: `<meu-componente algo="ctrl.variavelNoController">`. Daí só de alterar a `variavelNoController` já deveria refletir na diretiva. Mas se sua diretiva não pode utilizar isso devido as especificações dela, então seria mais fácil se tu compartilhasse teu código para analisarmos.

Comment: Consegui por meio de javaScript mesmo, so criei outro elemento div adicionei a direvtiva e coloquei por cima da anterior, Muito obrigado pela ajuda galera.